# MYSQL select additional fields than what I'm concatenating

Tags: mysql

I would just like to return additional fields NOT concatenated along with the the concatenated field I've set up.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT(vendor,gender,shopcategory,focusword, `year`) AS code
FROM store_data
WHERE type_id = 0
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  Were you just trying to do something like: `SELECT CONCAT(vendor,gender,shopcategory,focusword) AS code, year`?

Comment: Just add more columns to the `SELECT` list.  `SELECT CONCAT(a,b,c,d) as code, other1, other2, other3...FROM store_data`

Comment: I guess this is why SO insists on min. 15 character comments

Comment: Yep.. thanks. Just a newbie. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply list the additional fields after (or before your CONCAT):

```
SELECT CONCAT(vendor,gender,shopcategory,focusword, `year`) AS code, exampleField1, exampleField2
FROM store_data
WHERE type_id = 0
```